# How to add a new array to the current array element in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an array of users in local storage:

```
let btnSignUp = document.getElementById("btnSignUp");
btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let existingUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allUsers"));
  if (existingUsers == null) existingUsers = [];

  let userLogin = document.getElementById('authLogin').value;
  let userEmail = document.getElementById('authEmail').value;
  let userPassword = document.getElementById('authPassword').value;
  let userConfirmPassword = document.getElementById('authConfirmPassword').value;
  if (userPassword == userConfirmPassword) {
    let users = {
      "login": userLogin,
      "email": userEmail,
      "password": userPassword,
      "contacts": []
    };
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
    // Save allEntries back to local storage
    existingUsers.push(users);
    localStorage.setItem("allUsers", JSON.stringify(existingUsers));
  } else {
    alert("Password and confirm password must be the same");
  }
}, false);
```

And now I need to create an array of contacts for the selected user. Contact should look something like this:

```
let userSurname = document.getElementById('_surname').value;
let userName = document.getElementById('_name').value;
let userCountry = document.getElementById('_country').value;
let userCity = document.getElementById('_city').value;
let userEmail = document.getElementById('_email').value;
let userPhone = document.getElementById('_phone').value;
let userWorkPlace = document.getElementById('_workPlace').value;

let contact = {
  "surname": userSurname,
  "name": userName,
  "country": userCountry,
  "city": userCity,
  "email": userEmail,
  "phone": userPhone,
  "workPlace": userWorkPlace
};
localStorage.setItem("contact", JSON.stringify(contact));
```

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of contact object.`JSON.stringify` that array of contact objects

```
 let contacts = [];
 let contactObj = {
  "surname": userSurname,
  "name": userName,
  "country": userCountry,
  "city": userCity,
  "email": userEmail,
  "phone": userPhone,
  "workPlace": userWorkPlace
};
contacts.push(contactObj)
localStorage.setItem("contact", JSON.stringify(contacts));
```

Comment: ok, but now I need to take a list of users `let existingUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allUsers"));` and add, for example, to first user this array. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is on repeatedly having to de-serialize and serialize the contacts list of a particular user, you may use following two functions to persist contacts in localstorage. This might not be a perfect solution. But this addresses your concern. Try to build your own solution on this, based on your requirement.

To persist contacts

```
function addContact(username,contact){
    let count = localStorage.getItem(username+"-contacts-count") || 0;
    contact.index = count;
    localStorage.setItem(username+'-contact-'+(count++),JSON.stringify(contact));
    localStorage.setItem(username+"-contacts-count",count);
}
```

To retrieve contacts

```
function getContacts(username){
    let count = localStorage.getItem(username+"-contacts-count") || 0;
    let contacts = [];
    for(let i = 0;i<count;i++){
        let contact = localStorage.getItem(username+'-contact-'+(i));
        if(contact){
            contacts.push(JSON.parse(contact));
        }
    }
    return contacts;
}
```